# MySQL 8 replication: is it possible to specify master side a specific port for replication, and only replication (different than the default 3306)

Tags: mysql, replication, configuration

Master side.

In MySQL 8 for the replication, is it possible to specify master side a specific port for replication, and only replication that is different than the default 3306 where regular clients connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source instance is using a port other than 3306, the replica instances need to specify that when they configure replication.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/change-replication-source-to.html

```
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO ...
  SOURCE_PORT = 3307,
  ...
```

Because what if you were running multiple MySQL Server instances on the same source host? The replica would need to pick which one it connected to by specifying the SOURCE_PORT. There's no way for the source to tell the replica which port to use before the replica connects.

---

Re your comment:

Okay, I see what you're asking. I misunderstood.

MySQL 8.0 supports an optional second port. It is not enabled by default. It is intended to be used for "admin" purposes, but as far as I know, there's no reason you can't use it for replication. I think you would need to grant the `SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN` privilege to the user you use for replication.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/administrative-connection-interface.html for details on this feature and how to enable it.